# Making Templates generic

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that has some cells (not columns) that need to switch from readonly to editable based on some value in the viewmodel. The only way I could find to do this (after much searching) is something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding MyValue}"
            Style="{StaticResource CellTextBlockNumber}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReadonlyCellTemplate">
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding MyValue}"
            Style="{StaticResource CellTextBlockNumberReadonly}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableCellTemplate">
        <TextBox
            Text="{Binding MyValue}"
            Style="{StaticResource CellTextBoxNumber}"
            FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The various styles just do things like set background colors etc.

Then in the DataGrid.Columns sections:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnableCells}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ReadonlyCellTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource EditableCellTemplate}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnableCells}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ReadonlyCellTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So basically the ContentPresenter's ContentTemplate is being swapped out based on a DataTrigger.

This works fine for a single column, but I have about 10 columns that need this ability (at the cell level), and I really don't want to create 3 templates per column if I don't have to. Is there a way to modify this so the templates bind to a "generic" value (instead of MyValue) that I can specify at the DataGridColumn level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the templates that you already have, only change is that in the text block the text should be `Text="{Binding }"`.

Then in content control (in the cell/edit template), have the content bound like this:

```
Content="{Binding MyValue}"
```

So now you'll have only three templates and at each column you can specify a different binding for the content of the content control.

Comment: This seems close. It works for the CellTemplate, but when I double click to edit I get a xaml exception: "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath"

Comment: Add `Path=.` in the binding of text property in the text box.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why I wouldn't be able to copy the value from the textblock using this method with CTRL-C?

Comment: text **block**? It doesn't allow CTRL+C in any case, AFAIK.

Comment: What I don't understand is, when I select a datagrid cell that I haven't modified in the way specified above, just a normal cell in "non-edit" mode, I can copy the value. But if I select one of the cells that I have modified, I can not copy the value. Not being able to copy a textblock's value makes sense, but if that's the case, how do I create a cell whose value can be copied but not changed?

Comment: Aha! Set on the text block `Background="Transparent"` and then give it a context menu with a menu item that has `Command="Copy"`. The Copy command copies the item that has keyboard focus and that should be the cell, since text block don't get keyboard focus.